# how to remove nginx modules? - Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan

Tags: nginx

Hi I have something problem with nginx. When I get restarted nginx I take this error in log and nginx does not start. Only recently i have encountered an error something below.

ON log file `"/var/log/nginx/error.log`

`[info]: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:71`

I don't think i would need nchan module for a simple wordpress site.
I'm using ubuntu OS. My question is how do i remove nchan module?

Comment: did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Find the Modules which you want to remove or disable in the path -  `/etc/nginx/modules-enabled`

For nchan module the name will be something like - `50-mod-nchan.conf` or similar

You can delete the symbolic link formed with modules by following the below steps in Linux.

**Note:** To remove a symlink, you need to have writing permissions on the directory that contains the symlink. Otherwise, you will get “Operation not permitted” error.

To delete a symbolic link, run the unlink command followed by the symlink name as an argument:

```
unlink symlink_name      eg: unlink 50-mod-nchan.conf
```

Then restart the Nginx server.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). Also read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).